# Configure Reverse DNS in Primary and Secondary BIND DNS Servers for same subnet

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, reverse-dns, named-conf

I have two DNS Servers (Let's say **A** and **B**).

**A** configured as the **primary/master** for the domain **example.com** and **B** configured as the **secondary/slave** for the same domain.

**B** configured as the **primary/master** for the domain **my-domain.example.com** and **A** configured as the **secondary/slave** for the same subdomain.

I have A record for hostA.example.com pointed to 192.0.2.1 defined in A name server (master for example.com) and A record for hostB.my-domain.example.com pointed to 192.0.2.2 defined in B name server (master for my-domain.example.com).

How do I define reverse DNS zones in named.conf of A name server? Is the following configuration correct? Can I have two reverse DNS files for same subnet?

```
zone "2.0.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
type master;
file "***PATH/TO/REVERSE/DNS/MASTER/FILE***";
allow-update {none;};
allow-transfer {***TRUSTED_DNS_SERVERS_BY_A_NAME_SERVER***;};
allow-query {any; localhost;};
};

zone "2.0.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
type slave;
file "***PATH/TO/REVERSE/DNS/SLAVE/FILE***";
masters {NAME_SERVER_B;};
allow-transfer {***TRUSTED_DNS_SERVERS_BY_A_NAME_SERVER***;};
allow-query {any; localhost;};
};
```

Comment: "Can I have two reverse DNS files for same subnet?" No, or at least not in the same view. Your setup is quite complicated, why having B a primary for a zone delegated out of A for which B is secondary? PS: please do not obfuscate IP addresses badly. I edited your post.

Comment: Thank you Patrick! Actually these name servers located at two different places. People at the location which the B name server is located should have the capability of adding entries for the zone delegated out of A.